# $\partial M = \overline{M} \cap( \mathbb{R}^d\backslash \mathring{M})$

Tags: general-topology

I need to show the following:

$\partial M = \overline{M} \cap( \mathbb{R}^d\backslash \mathring{M})$

Unfortunately i have absolutely no idea how to show that. 
Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: How have you defined the boundary of a set $M$?

Comment: for all epsilon > 0 : ball with radius epsilon of x intersect with M is empty set and same with M^c

Comment: Don't you mean intersection *is not* empty? otherwise the definition is not correct. Btw, you can also use LaTeX formatting in the comments, this will make what you write clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The proof will depend on how you define the boundary of a set in the first place. You seem to have it defined this way:

$$\partial M := \left\{x \in \mathbb R^d : \forall \varepsilon > 0 : B(x, \varepsilon) \cap M \neq \emptyset \text{ and } B(x, \varepsilon) \cap M^\complement \neq \emptyset\right\}.$$

You want to show the equality between two sets, i.e. you need to prove that each one is a subset of the other.

### Show that $\partial M \subseteq \overline M \cap (\mathbb R^d \setminus \mathring M)$

Take $x \in \partial M$. To show $x \in \overline M$, you can define a sequence $(x_n)_{n \geq 1}$ in $M$ as follows: for $n \geq 1$, define arbitrarily $x_n \in B(x, 1/n) \cap M$ (which is not empty). By construction, the sequence will convergence towards $x$, hence $x \in \overline M$. You can show that $x \in R^d \setminus \mathring M$ using the same argument with $M^\complement$ instead of $M$ (since $\mathbb R^d \setminus \mathring M$ is the complement of an open set, i.e. a closed set).

### Show that $\partial M \supseteq \overline M \cap (\mathbb R^d \setminus \mathring M)$

Take $y \in \overline M \cap (\mathbb R^d \setminus \mathring M)$. If you reverse the argument (take a sequence $(y_n)_{n \geq 1}$ in $M$ converging towards $y$), you can show that for every $\varepsilon > 0$: $M \cap B(y, \varepsilon) \neq \emptyset$ because it must contain at least one of the $y_n$'s. And again, you can use the same argument to show that for every $\varepsilon > 0$: $B(y, \varepsilon) \cap M^\complement$ cannot be empty by taking the sequence in $\mathbb R^d \setminus \mathring M$.